# How to remove array from a response?

Tags: arrays, bash, snmp

I am using SNMPGET to SNMP the values of some batteries. The problem is that batteries 4 and 8 are optional. So sometimes the response can be inconsistent where you get a battery voltage, for example "13.40" or you get a response of "No Such Instance currently exists at this OID". My goal is to collect the data and store it in a database. But can someone recommend how I can manage the inconsistency of batteries 4 and 8?

```
IP=192.168.1.0


##MY MIB FILE
sysdesc=iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0
mac=iso.3.6.1.4.1.5591.1.3.2.7.0
logical_name=iso.3.6.1.4.1.5591.1.3.1.1.0
Batt1_1_VDC=1.3.6.1.4.1.5591.1.4.4.1.4.1.1.1
Batt1_2_VDC=1.3.6.1.4.1.5591.1.4.4.1.4.1.1.2
Batt1_3_VDC=1.3.6.1.4.1.5591.1.4.4.1.4.1.1.3
Batt1_4_VDC=1.3.6.1.4.1.5591.1.4.4.1.4.1.1.4
Batt2_1_VDC=1.3.6.1.4.1.5591.1.4.4.1.4.1.2.1
Batt2_2_VDC=1.3.6.1.4.1.5591.1.4.4.1.4.1.2.2
Batt2_3_VDC=1.3.6.1.4.1.5591.1.4.4.1.4.1.2.3
Batt2_4_VDC=1.3.6.1.4.1.5591.1.4.4.1.4.1.2.4

OUTPUT=`snmpget -v2c -c public -Oqv $IP'\
' $sysdesc'\
' $logical_name'\
' $mac'\
' $Batt1_1_VDC'\
' $Batt1_2_VDC'\
' $Batt1_3_VDC'\
' $Batt1_4_VDC'\
' $Batt2_1_VDC'\
' $Batt2_2_VDC'\
' $Batt2_3_VDC'\
' $Batt2_4_VDC`

eval ARRAY=($OUTPUT)
echo "${ARRAY[*]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use snmpwalk instead of snmpget. This will give you the values for each battery, regardless of how many there are. You will still have to loop through the results. If you need to know which value is from which battery you will have to drop the -Ov flag.

```
snmpget -v2c -c public -Oq 192.168.1.0 1.3.6.1.4.1.5591.1.4.4.1.4.1
```

Comment: I hear what you are saying appreciate the feedback, I have to compare each result because the number of batteries vary so I have a check in the sysdesc but you are right....